# All combination from list of lists

Tags: c#

I have list of lists. For example:

```
  List<List<string>> bigList = new List<List<string>>();

        var l1 = new List<string>();
        l1.Add("a1");
        l1.Add("a2");
        l1.Add("a3");

        var l2 = new List<string>();
        l2.Add("b1");
        l2.Add("b2");

        var l3 = new List<string>();
        l3.Add("c1");
        l3.Add("c2");

        bigList.Add(l1);
        bigList.Add(l2);
        bigList.Add(l3);
```

I need to create new list of lists, that will have 12 elements in my example (3*2*2). I need all combinations.

Result should be like this:

```
            //a1,b1,c1
            //a1,b1,c2
            //a1,b2,c1
            //a1,b2,c2    
            //a2,b1,c1
            //a2,b1,c2
            //a2,b2,c1
            //a2,b2,c2
            //a3,b1,c1
            //a3,b1,c2
            //a3,b2,c1
            //a3,b2,c2
```

Off course should work for any list of lists. Not just for this example. I realy have problem to write this algorithm. Thanks for help.

Comment: This not duplicate. In may case don't know how many list of lists I have. In example is 3 but it can be 15 lists.

Comment: @user2451446 Come on. At least try to read the post. (See the Eric Lippert's blog linked in his  answer)